# Счетчик переполнений таймера не работает

Tags: c, arm, прерывания, миландр

В микроконтроллере 1986ВЕ92У все таймеры 16-разрядные, и этой разрядности недостаточно, чтобы охватить весь диапазон периодов прямоугольного сигнала, который поступает на канал захвата. Делители вводить нельзя, так как от этого уменьшится его разрешение. Поэтому я принял решение считать количество переполнений основного счётчика таймера, и исходя из этого рассчитывать итоговую длину импульса. Но этот счетчик работает неправильно. Вот инициализация таймера (здесь и далее сокращение temp - температура):

```
void InitTemp()
{
    PORT_InitTypeDef portInitStruct;
    TIMER_CntInitTypeDef timInitStruct;
    TIMER_ChnInitTypeDef timChStruct;

    TIMER_BRGInit(TEMP_TIMER, TIMER_HCLKdiv1);
    PORT_StructInit(&portInitStruct);
    portInitStruct.PORT_Pin = TEMP_PORT_PIN;
    portInitStruct.PORT_OE = PORT_OE_IN;
    portInitStruct.PORT_FUNC = PORT_FUNC_ALTER;
    portInitStruct.PORT_SPEED = PORT_SPEED_MAXFAST;
    portInitStruct.PORT_MODE = PORT_MODE_DIGITAL;
    PORT_Init(TEMP_PORT, &portInitStruct);

    TIMER_CntStructInit(&timInitStruct);
    timInitStruct.TIMER_Period = 0xffff;
    timInitStruct.TIMER_Prescaler = (SystemCoreClock / (1000000 * TEMP_TIMER_CLK_PRESC)) - 1;
    TIMER_CntInit(TEMP_TIMER, &timInitStruct);

    TIMER_ChnStructInit(&timChStruct);
    timChStruct.TIMER_CH_Mode = TIMER_CH_MODE_CAPTURE;
    timChStruct.TIMER_CH_Number = TEMP_TIMER_CHANNEL;
    TIMER_ChnInit(TEMP_TIMER, &timChStruct);

    TIMER_ITConfig(TEMP_TIMER, TEMP_TIMER_INTERRUPT | TIMER_STATUS_CNT_ZERO, ENABLE);
    TIMER_Cmd(TEMP_TIMER, ENABLE);  
}
```

В обработчике прерывания проверяю, что именно произошло: захват канала или переполнение:

```
void Timer1_IRQHandler()
{
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(Timer1_IRQn);
    if (TIMER_GetITStatus(TEMP_TIMER, TEMP_TIMER_INTERRUPT) == SET)
    {
            TIMER_ClearITPendingBit(TEMP_TIMER, TEMP_TIMER_INTERRUPT);
            HandleTempPeriod();
    }
    else if (TIMER_GetITStatus(TEMP_TIMER, TIMER_STATUS_CNT_ARR) == SET)
    {
            HandleTempOverrun();
            TIMER_ClearITPendingBit(TEMP_TIMER, TIMER_STATUS_CNT_ARR);
    }
}
```

Подсчитываю количество переполнений:

```
volatile uint32_t tempOverrunCount = 0;    
void HandleTempOverrun()
{
    tempOverrunCount++;
}
```

И вычисляю длину импульса:

```
void HandleTempPeriod()
{
    static uint32_t rv1, rv2;
    static uint32_t period = 0;
    static uint32_t overrun = 0;
    if (tempsensor.captureState == FirstNotCaptured)
    {
            rv1 = TEMP_TIMER->CCR1;
            tempsensor.captureState = FirstCaptured;
            tempOverrunCount = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
            overrun = tempOverrunCount;
            rv2 = TEMP_TIMER->CCR1;
            if (overrun > 0)
            {
                period = TEMP_TIMER->ARR - rv1 + TEMP_TIMER->ARR * (overrun - 1) + rv2;
            }
            else
            {
                period = rv2 - rv1;
            }
            rv1 = rv2;
            tempOverrunCount = tempOverrunCount - overrun;          
    }
}
```

В результате часто наблюдаются случаи, когда переменная `overrun` становится единицей, когда переполнения на самом деле не было, а также нулём, когда переполнение было. В документе errata на этот контроллер указано, что выставление флага захвата и обновление регистра `CCRx` разнесены на один такт таймера, поэтому в регистре на момент чтения может быть старое значение, однако от момента прерывания до чтения регистра проходит достаточное количество тактов процессора, чтобы таймер обновился. Поэтому эта ошибка исключена. Также я пробовал вместо регистра `CCR1` читать `CNT`, результат тот же. Что я делаю не так?

p.s. Если здесь есть представители Миландра, обратите внимание: на вашем форуме не работает регистрация. Не приходит письмо активации.

Comment: У вас плохо написан обработчик прерываний. Что сразу бросается в глаза: а) вначале что-то делаем, **потом** очищаем биты, а не наоборот; б) а вы не подумали, что статус может быть не только *или-или*? Надо считывать статус во временную переменную  и обрабатывать соответствующим образом (no else!). И сверху всего этого отстутствие синхронизации записи-чтения глобальной переменной (должна быть atomic).

Comment: @0andriy, конечно, может быть не только *или-или*, но это не должно быть причиной проблемы: если хотя бы один флаг прерывания остался поднятым, программа снова вернётся в обработчик после его завершения. Почему флаги прерывания нужно сбрасывать в конце обработчика? И какие именно флаги имеете в виду: NVIC или периферии? Насчет atomic тоже не уверен, так как исключен одновременный вызов функций `HandleTempPeriod` и `HandleTempOverrun`: они вызываются только из одного обработчика прерывания, а прерывание не может быть вложено само в себя.

Comment: Попробовал перенести сброс флагов в конец, убрал else в обработчике прерывания. Не помогло.